# Add a counter for url shortener in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello i'm building an app to shorten urls using nodejs and mongodb
I want to add a counter to each url added to the data base and how many times it was shortened for example
For now it just shortens the url once and gives me the date of the last time i shortened the url

this is my db.config

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Url = require('../models/url');


const db = "mongodb://localhost:27017/url"



mongoose.createConnection(db, err =>{
    if(err){
        console.error('Error! ' + err)
    } else {
      console.log('Connected to mongodb url')      
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const URLSchema = new Schema({
    urlCode: String,
    longUrl: String,
    shortUrl: String,
    date: {
        type: String,
        default: Date.now
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('url', URLSchema, 'urls');
```

and this is the api

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const validUrl = require('valid-url');
const shortid = require('shortid');
const config = require('config');

const Url = require('../models/url');

router.post('/shorten', async (req, res) => {
  const { longUrl } = req.body;
  const baseUrl = config.get('baseUrl');

  // Check base url
  if (!validUrl.isUri(baseUrl)) {
    return res.status(401).json('Invalid base url');
  }

  // Create url code
  const urlCode = shortid.generate();

  // Check long url
  if (validUrl.isUri(longUrl)) {
    try {
      let url = await Url.findOne({ longUrl });

      if (url) {
        res.json(url);
      } else {
        const shortUrl = baseUrl + '/' + urlCode;

        url = new Url({
          longUrl,
          shortUrl,
          urlCode,
          date: new Date()
        });

        await url.save();

        res.json(url);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json('Server error');
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).json('Invalid long url');
  }
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Url.find({},(err, docs) => {
        if (!err) { res.send(docs); }
        else { console.log('Error in Retriving url :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Add another field in your schema with a name `count`, then you can check whether this long url exists in the db, if yes, then increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const URLSchema = new Schema({
    urlCode: String,
    longUrl: String,
    shortUrl: String,
    date: {
        type: String,
        default: Date.now
    },
    count: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('url', URLSchema, 'urls');
```

And, the updated API

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const validUrl = require('valid-url');
const shortid = require('shortid');
const config = require('config');

const Url = require('../models/url');

router.post('/shorten', async (req, res) => {
  const { longUrl } = req.body;
  const baseUrl = config.get('baseUrl');

  // Check base url
  if (!validUrl.isUri(baseUrl)) {
    return res.status(401).json('Invalid base url');
  }

  // Create url code
  const urlCode = shortid.generate();

  // Check long url
  if (validUrl.isUri(longUrl)) {
    try {
      let url = await Url.findOne({ longUrl });

      if (url) {
        await Url.updateOne({ longUrl }, { count: url.count + 1 }, { upsert: true })
        res.json(url);
      } else {
        const shortUrl = baseUrl + '/' + urlCode;

        url = new Url({
          longUrl,
          shortUrl,
          urlCode,
          date: new Date()
        });

        await url.save();

        res.json(url);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json('Server error');
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).json('Invalid long url');
  }
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Url.find({},(err, docs) => {
        if (!err) { res.send(docs); }
        else { console.log('Error in Retriving url :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});



module.exports = router;
```